# Where is the appropriate place to instantiate a javascript widget/chart/utility when using angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas, chart.js

I'm using chart.js to make, unsurprisingly, a chart, and I'm trying to figure out how to cleanly and correctly rewrite my code in angular.js.

### Vanilla Implementation

If I were just using vanilla javascript and html, I'd probably do something that boils down to this:

```
<canvas id='chart'></canvas>
<script>
    data = {...} // dictionary of chart data, omitted for brevity
    options = {...} // dictionary of chart options, same^
    var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");
    var chart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, options);
</script>
```

And first the canvas would load, then the script would run and draw the chart.

### Angular

But with angular, I can have, instead,

```
<ng-chart></ng-chart>
<script>
    angular.module('app')
    .directive('ngChart', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<canvas></canvas>'
            ...
        }
    )
</script>
```

and put the same javascript from the first example inside the directive.

...

But where?

It seems like it should be in either a link function, or the controller.  I need the DOM elements to load first, because otherwise drawing on the canvas won't work--but that doesn't seem to limit it.  I also would like to be able to re-draw the graph, so that I can eventually add the ability to filter/rescale the graph without reloading the whole page.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if this is what you're asking, but your script should be inside the `head` tag, preferably in a linked `.js` file. The same goes for your first example, you would just have to make sure the DOM was loaded before initializing it.

Comment: Yeah it's in another file and referenced from inside the head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

under the `link` property.

```
<script>
    angular.module('app')
    .directive('ngChart', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, controllers) {
                //your plugin implementation here
                data = {...} // dictionary of chart data, omitted for brevity
                options = {...} // dictionary of chart options, same^
                var ctx = element.getContext("2d");
                var chart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, options);
            }
            template: '<canvas></canvas>'

        }
    )
</script>
```

Comment: Can you explain *why* it should be under the link property?